# laravel update status to 0 or 1 when button is toggled in a single row using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm relatively new to Laravel. I'm trying to update the 'is_active' column in mysql when the button is toggled without reloading the page. Each row of the table will have the button. I'm also trying to display a pop out message when button is toggled by having the same effect as bootstrap delete confirmation modal.

What i have up to until now is making the toggle button work, but when i tried to toggle the button, there is no changes made to the database. I'm thinking whether should i use a form for the checkbox

UPDATED

This is how my button looks like in html

```
@foreach($system_functions as $function)
    <input type="hidden" id="id_input" value="{{$function->id}}" >
    @if($function->group_id == 1)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $function->name !!}</td>
            <td><input class="toggle_status" type="checkbox" @if($function->is_active) checked @endif id="is_active" name="is_active" value="on" data-toggle="toggle"></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I also have an update function in controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $function=SystemFunction::where('id',$id)->first();
    if($request->get('is_active')==='on'){
        $is_active=1;
    } else{
        $is_active=0;
    }
    $function->update([
        'is_active' => $is_active
    ]);
    return redirect('admin/system-functions')->with('status','SUCCESSFUL');
}
```

and i'm calling this in my route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'staff'), function () {
    Route::post('/system-functions', 'SystemFunctionController@update')->name('system-functions');
}
```

and my js looks like this in my view

```
@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('.toggle_status').on('click', function (e) {
            var is_checked = false
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                is_checked = true;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('admin.system-functions') }}', // use proper route to system-functions here
                async: true,
                data: {
                    is_checked: is_checked,
                    id: {{ $function->id }}
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Toggle successfull'); // use proper alert message here
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

console error
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abcaL.png)

Comment: do you have js code to send reqquest to server?

Comment: nope, i dont have

Comment: Looks like you are POSTing isChecked data and storing isActive :) Hope that works XD.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<tr>
    <td>{!! $function->id !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $function->name !!}</td>
    <td><input class="togglefunction" type="checkbox" @if($function->is_active) checked @endif id="is_active" name="is_active"  value="on" data-toggle="toggle" data-fid="{{$function->id}}"></td>
 </tr>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/system-functions', 'SystemFunctionController@update')->name('update-system-function');
```

In Model

```
public function toggleIsActive()
     {
            $this->is_active= !$this->is_active;
            return $this;
     }
```

then use like

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $function=SystemFunction::where('id',$request->id)->first();
    $function->toggleIsActive()->save();
    return redirect('admin/system-functions')->with('status','successful');
}
```

javascript :

```
$('.togglefunction').on('click',function(){  
    //send value by ajax to server
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{route('update-system-function')}}',
        type:'GET',
        data:"{id:$(this).data('fid')}"
    }).done(function(response) {
      //success
       }).fail(function(error){
      //failure
       })
});
```

Comment: don't i need a js to send request to server ?

Comment: you have submit button ?

Comment: if you want to do ajax then you need simple javascript

Comment: i dont have submit button, i just have this toggle button

Comment: whatever if you want .done{} is for success like alert on is active enable or disable .  and .fail{} for error

Comment: how ajax get method work with post route? I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to do ajax call on each click on a checkbox to update database record.**

**Your js code will be like this:**

```
$('#somecheckbox').on('click',function(){
    //check the checkbox status
    var is_checked  = false
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       is_checked = true;
    }
    //send value by ajax to server
    $.ajax({
        url:'url_here',
        type:'GET',
        data:"{is_checked:is_checked}"
    }).done(function(response) {
      //success
       }).fail(function(error){
      //failure
       })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#is_active").click(function() {
        var checkBoxe = $("#is_active");
        checkBoxe.prop("checked", !checkBoxe.prop("checked"));
    });  

    var checkedValue = $('#is_active').val();
    var id = $('#id_input').val();

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", '{{url('system-functions')}}'+'/'+checkedValue+'/'+id, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', '');
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }              
});
```

and your route here...

```
Route::get('/system-functions/{value}/{id}', 'SystemFunctionController@update');
```

your server method here...

```
public function update($value,$id)
{
    $function=SystemFunction::where('id',$id)->first();
    if($value==='checked'){
        $is_active=1;
    } else{
        $is_active=0;
    }
    $function->update([
        'is_active' => $is_active
    ]);
    echo 'Successfully!'
}
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: add this input to your foreach <input type="hidden" id="id_input" value="{{$function->id}}" />

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: there's no error on the console, but just the db is not updating and the changes is not being made

Comment: did you remove $function->save(); from your controller methd??

Comment: there's this console error GET https://localhost:8443/CLodopfuncs.js?priority=2 0 ()

Answer (score 0):

I Like javascript code of @DejavuGuy's Answers to imporove backend code I would like to suggest you to use something like this:

```
public function update($value,$id)
{
    $function=SystemFunction::where('id',$id)->first();
    $function->is_active = !$function->is_active;
    $function->save();
    echo 'Successfully!'
}
```

Good luck